# Docker start privileged?

Tags: docker

I'm quite new to docker.I have a docker container running.

```
[root@vm Downloads]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
fc86020fff36        centos:6.6          "/bin/bash"         5 days ago          Up 17 hours                             drunk_tesla
```

I want to stop this vm and run it as --privileged. But I have bunch of things in this docker.

I don't want to use --run because it creates a new docker instance and i have to re-do everything.

Is there anyway i can stop and start the docker container in privileged mode?

Thanks,
r

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the docker image you used ([centos:6.6](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/8911843d9a6cc71aadd81e491f94618aded94f30/docker/Dockerfile)) for creating this container has no volumes, that means that any data you modified in this container is written on the container filesystem itself (as opposed to [*on a docker volume*](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)).

The [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) command will take the content of a container filesystem *(excluding volumes)* and produce a new docker image from it. This way you will be able to create a new container from that new image that will have the same content.

```
docker commit drunk_tesla mycentosimage
docker run -it --privileged mycentosimage bash
```

Comment: Running `docker exec -it  --privileged drunk_tesla bash` has worked for me, so as for 2022 you don't have to go through all this

Comment: why can't i just click "privileged mode" - i'm on windows and don't wanna use the bad and ugly windows terminal